# Installing C header files for libraries with many headers

Tags: c, unix, autotools

I'm using GNU autotools to build a library (let's call it libfoo) which will probably contain lots of header files, as I use a "one header per source file" approach.

If I were to use libfoo in another project, I would probably not want to include them at the granularity in which they are defined in the source, but would want to include them in larger chunks.

My first approach to this was to make a header `foo.h` and include the other headers into that header, so a user would only have to include `foo.h`, but this would still require installing the smaller headers (thus cluttering up the users include directory), as includes in `foo.h` aren't handled during libfoo's build, but only when the header is used.

I know I could just define everything that is part of the public API in `foo.h`, but that would result in a big cluttered header file and I prefer not to do that.

What is the usual approach to this?

Comment: Creating a sub-directory for your (multiple) header files inside the users include directory (e.g. `/include/foo`) won't clutter up the directory.

Comment: @tversteeg That probably makes the most sense. For some reason that didn't occur to me.

Comment: @tversteeg: putting user-installed headers at root-level? Very bad idea!

Comment: @Olaf I meant `*/include/foo`, where `*` probably is `/usr` or `/usr/local`

Comment: @tversteeg One should respect the filesystem standard on the platform.

Comment: it does not matter how many header files are involved in the creation of the library.  When you want to access that library from user code, you only need to create a single header file that exposes all the 'user' entry points in the library AND any data definitions that the 'user' needs to know about.